# Replace spaces in URL after #

Tags: regex, url, replace, spaces

I have a database dump from Wordpress that has url's with spaces that I need to remove the spaces from. I thought this would be a lot simpler of a task. This is the expression to match the bad href's

```
(href\="http\:\/\/wfsu.org/blog-coastal-health\/\?page_id\=\d+\/\#)((\w+)\s(\w+))+\"
```

The problem is trying to replace the spaces with dashes ..

I'm replacing with `$1$3-$4"` which works fine on anything with 2 words but not with 3+ words. Anyone have any solution?

Comment: What is your current method that works with 2 words but not 3+ words?

Comment: why don't you just replace the white spaces? replace all \s for -

Comment: Trokka: using a texteditor called sublime edit, but i'm looking into using sed
Matheus: The file is a 6k line sql file if I replaced all spaces it would break a lot of things :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using `preg_replace_callback()`.  That would allow you to use regex to grab the URL string that you are interested in , then you could pass it to the callback function where you can easily use string manipulation to replace the spaces with dashes.

Your code might look something like this:

```
$original_string; // your original string holding your text content
$pattern = '~href="http://wfsu.org/blog-coastal-health/.*"~i';
$cleaned_string = preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern,
    function ($matches) {
        return str_replace(' ', '-', $matches[0]);
    },
    $original_string
);
```

This eliminates the need to try to determine how many pattern fragments you need to replace within the regex itself. Instead you capture the entire `href` property value and do a simple `str_replace()` on it.